# How can i transfer this from absolute value to a path(t)?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am trying to solve an Integral, but I need to transfer this circle to a parameterized path :

|z-3i| = 1

Comment: So it's the circle of radius one around $3i$. How do you parameterize a unit circle? Just add $3i$ to that.

Comment: it should be like this right ? γ(t)  = 3i  + e^it : 0≤ t≤ 2π. right  ?

Comment: Yes, that will work. If you propose that as a solution to this question, then you can accept it and we can provide feedback to your answer.